# Counting number of multiple consecutive patterns in a file

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file with numbers on each line. I am trying to count the number of multiples of '1' in each line; how many single 1s, double 1s (two consecutive ones on different lines), triple 1s (three consecutive ones on different lines) etc. Just the number 1 itself, not as part of a number.

For example for the following:

2131
1
132
1
121
43342
1
1
1
1314214
4214
1
1

There are two counts of: 1
There is one count of: 1\n 1
There is one count of: 1\n 1\n 1

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Comment: This looks like a home work problem that was just posted with little or no effort to actually figure out any solution.

Comment: Review the following: [ask]